# Remove span from div from an xpath selector in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I need to extract only 19.10 value in following html but my xpath is not working. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="class1">19.10
        <span class="class2"><br></span>
</div>
```

Xpath:

```
//div[@class='class1'][not(preceding::span[@class='class2'])]/text()
```

Result:

```
[u'19.10\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the first text element here. There are few ways of doing this. With xpath:

```
"/div[@class='class1'][not(preceding::span[@class='class2'])]/text()[1]"
```

or with post-processing:

```
# just first element
response.xpath("xpath").extract_first()
```

or if you are familiar with item loaders:

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    myfield_out = TakeFirst()
ml = MyItemLoader()
ml.add_xpath('myfield', 'xpath')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below xPath :-

```
string(//div[@class='class1'])
```

or

```
(//div[@class='class1']/text())[1]
```